# Is there a way to have sh/bash/zsh "case" use a variable for a test value?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, sh

I'd like to have something like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
# ... other stuff ...
# some relatively static possibilities (srsp):
srsp='this|or|that|the|other'
# more other stuff
case $something in
    $srsp) # <- problem is here
        do_something # or maybe nothing
        ;;
    this|or|that|the|other);; # this would work, but loses the benefit of a variable
    *)
        # anything not in my list is an error:
        echo "Sorry, I don't recognize $something as one of $srsp" >&2
        exit 1;;
esac

do_something | egrep "blah($srsp)thing" # or whatever
```

The problem is, having `$srsp` there only matches the whole string (if `$something` was exactly the string `"this|or|that|or|some|other|stuff"`, it would match and call `do_something`), rather than any of `this` or `or` or `that`... and so forth: the values I actually want to match.

If I put that literal string in the case statement (my "this would work" line), it matches what I want it to match, but I'm trying to keep this [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), and I need the same set of strings in the regular expression I use later.  (Side note: I understand that what's possible in a `case` match and what's possible in a regular expression can differ dramatically, but in my particular situation, they're compatible with both.  It really is just letters in the individual components, no wildcards, just the `|`, which exists as a special case in both systems.)

So, is there a way to do this?  Especially without wrapping the whole case statement inside an eval or something?  I'd like to still keep it in a case statement, because I have other stuff going on.  (I'm sure I could implement a workaround by re-structuring and using egrep as my match test (`if echo $something | egrep "^($srsp)$" > /dev/null`, or some such).  This question is about trying to find a way to do it without having to resort to that.  Or definitively knowing that it can't be done would also be a valid answer.)

(Or should I [switch to common-lisp](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GreenspunsTenthRuleOfProgramming)?  ;) )

For my needs, I'd be happy with `sh` or `bash` for sure, and *possibly* `zsh`, though if there's a way to do this in a maximally-portable way (i.e. `sh`), that would make for a better answer, IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really isn't about `case` per se: you need a mechanism to check if a word is present in a list. With bash you can do this:

```
srsp=(this that or the other)
in_srsp() {
    # this joins the array into a string with spaces (default value of IFS)
    # then tests if the space-delimited word is a match for that string.
    [[ " ${srsp[*]} " == *" $1 "* ]]
}
something=foo
if in_srsp $something; then echo y; else echo n; fi   # =>  n
something=other
if in_srsp $something; then echo y; else echo n; fi   # =>  y
```

More portably just turn the case around

```
srsp="this|that|or|the|other"
something=other
case "|$srsp|" in
    *"|$something|"*) echo in;;
    *) echo not;;
esac
```

Comment: Well, the first option here doesn't really work for me, because it loses the compatibility with egrep (and similar), which was a big part of the point.  Your latter suggestion does at least give me a match, though, and that works in this case.  (It would in principal be nice to not have to invert the case, but for my purposes, it'll do.)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval`, of course, but it is rather unwieldy.  Perhaps encapsulate it into a function so you can avoid too many backslashes outside of the actually complex `eval`.

```
in_list () {
    local var
    var=$1
    local list
    list=$2
    eval case \$var in "$list"\) return 0\;\; \*) return 1\;\; esac
}

in_list "foo" "foo|bar|baz" && echo Success
in_list "nonesvch" "foo|bar|baz" || echo More so
```

If you know you can restrict the character set in the list, maybe run a filtering `case` before the `eval` for security, something like

```
in_list () {
    local var
    var=$1
    local list
    list=$2

    case $var in *[!-a-z0-9_]*) return 1;; esac

    # Additionally, allow wildcards and whitespace in list
    case $list in *[!?*| a-z0-9_-]*)
        echo "$0: Invalid characters in $list" >&2; return 2;;
    esac

    eval case \$var in "$list"\) return 0\;\; \*) return 1\;\; esac
}
```

Comment: The difficulty I have with this is that while `$list` (as used here, `$srsp` in the original question) is safe to eval, because it's coded in the script, `$var` is actually getting data from the command line, and thus could contain things that would break syntax here.  It's possible this could be fixed with appropriate quoting?  But as you have it, this strikes me as insecure and thus problematic.  Still, I do like the idea of making a function out of this, so thank you for that... I might play with this more.

Comment: I updated the answer with a couple of prefiltering cases.  Hope this helps.

Comment: With that addition, this strikes me as a workable option (though I'm still going with http://superuser.com/a/883191/57367 for my particular situation).  Thanks!